# Date Picker Should not accept past dates which are less then the current date in android

Tags: android, datepicker

I am developing one app like reminder, in this user can create the task according to date. Here I want to restrict the user to not to select the past date which are less then the system current date. So that user wont create the task for the past dates. So, can any one help me out from this.

Thanks in advance
Ravi

Comment: How about just alerting the user that the date isn't possible if it is in the past?

Answer (score 1):

i'm thinking you are using datepicker dialog.if thats right then
in

```
OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                    int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                try {
                    Date selectedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse(year+"/"+monthOfYear+"/"+dayOfMonth);
Date currDate = new Date();
if(selectedDate.compareTo(currDate ) >=0 ){
//then do your work
}else{
//show message
}

}catch(Exception e){
  e.getMessage();

}
```

Comment: Thanks. But i face problem with comparison of current date.
So I changed if loop with

if(selectedDate.compareTo(currDate ) >=0 || selectedDate.compareTo(currDate ) ==-1)

and I got result.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `OnDateSetListener`  like folowing

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
        int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    //here we get the selected date, so we can compare the date with current date 
            //and perform required operation

}
```